# Checking if variable used in an if statement exists

Tags: python

I have made a program that sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't.
I have no idea why and the code is really simple (I am using an unofficial firmware for external hardware so it's likely a bug there).

To fix this, I made a check that determines if the program is going correctly or not.

This is the roughly the code:

```
if variable > whatever.value()
    ....
else: 
    ....
    variable = ....
```

`variable` is not initialized before.

Would this work? Or is this is wrong and there is a clean way to do this? (The code is in a while loop)

Comment: Of course there is a clean way. Either give variable a value if None beforehand and check for that. Or probably the value in the else clause.

Comment: try using try except ?

Comment: No this won't work. "name 'variable' is not defined" would get thrown. It won't make it to the else. You would need try/except.

Comment: You can catch the `NameError`, but it would be far better to design your code to ensure `variable` *is* defined in the first place.

Comment: if you just want to be sure it runs for the first time you can initialize `variable = float('inf')`

Comment: Don't put band-aids on symptoms, fix the problem.

Comment: @Barmar I would, but I don't think that the problem is my code here.

Comment: No, the problem is in the earlier code that isn't initializing `variable`. Fix that.

Answer (score 0):

try `locals()` for local variables, `globals()` for global variables.

```
if variable in locals():
  # variable named 'variable' exists
else:
  variable = "I exist!"
```

Comment: This is NEVER a solution to a problem. Not defining variables is a big that needs fixing. Not working around.

Comment: @deets that was his use case, his choice to figure things out, and I provided a legit solution for him. In this regard, I believe that my solution do not deserve a downvote. Nevertheless, I would be pleased to know if these is an alternative way you can suggest to solve this issue.

Comment: The alternative is to define variables properly so you can’t run into a situation where one code path introduces one and another one not. You can e.g. assign None and later check for that instead. And giving an answer like yours to a code quality problem reinforces bad coding, leading to increased problems further down. Thus it warrants a Downvote.